# Update EditText from one fragment to another using interface

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a `Visual Studio Xamarin` based Android project, in which I have an activity with 4 fragments. Fragments are added to the activity using a `ViewPagerAdapter`. I am trying to update an `EditText` on a second fragment using the value from first fragment. I used an interface to achieve this but I have some issues.
Below is my first fragment which provides the value to update the EditText in second fragment:

My Interface:

```
public interface IOnFragmentDetailsCallbackReceived
{
    void UpdatePackageNo(string updatedPackageNo);
}
```

My OnAttach:

```
public override void OnAttach(Context context)
    {
        base.OnAttach(context);
        _updatedPackageNo = (IOnFragmentDetailsCallbackReceived) context;
    }
```

How I get the value:

```
private void AddPackageToList()
    {
        _packages.Add(_labelPackage);
        _adapterPackage = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, _packages.ToArray());
        _adapterPackage.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        _listViewPackages.Adapter = _adapterPackage;

        //update the  orders counter
        _txtViewPackagesCount.Text = $"({Packages.Count})";

        _updatedPackageNo.UpdatePackageNo(Packages.Count.ToString());
    }
```

So far the value is retrieved correctly. Now below you can see the code that I have in my activity:

```
public void UpdatePackageNo(string updatedPackageNo)
    {
        FragmentDetails newFragmentDetails = new FragmentDetails();
        newFragmentDetails.GetStringFromFragOrders(updatedPackageNo);
    }
```

For the above, I am getting the correct value from the fragment.
Below I will show you the code I have in my second fragment where I am trying to update the EditText value:

```
 public void OnFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus)
    {
        GetStringFromFragOrders(_editTextNoOfPackages.Text);
    }

    public void GetStringFromFragOrders(string updatedPackageNo)
    {
        _editTextNoOfPackages.SetText(updatedPackageNo, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    }
```

The problem I am having is that **inside the `GetStringFromFragOrders(string updatedPackageNo)` method, the `_editTextNoOfPackages` is always `null`**.
On this fragment I have other `EditText` fields for which I want to preserve the value. 
I tried below code in the Activity:

```
public void UpdatePackageNo(string updatedPackageNo)
    {
        FragmentDetails fragment = new FragmentDetails();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.PutString("packageNo", updatedPackageNo);
        fragment.Arguments = args;

        FragmentTransaction transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.create_frame, fragment, "updatedFragment");
        transaction.AddToBackStack("updatedFragment");
        transaction.Commit();
    }
```

And in the receiving fragment I used the following:

```
 _receivedData = Arguments.GetString("packageNo");

public void OnFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus)
    {
        _editTextNoOfPackages.Text = _receivedData;
    }
```

This updates the `EditText` but unfortunately wipes all the other `EditText` data, because of the replace statement.
 **How can I update one `EditText` without wiping the data from all the other ones?**
If anyone can see a fix in order to achieve the desired outcome please leave some comments.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it is, create a static string in your first fragment and change it to the string present in editText, and now you can use this static variable in your second fragment for retrieving the data of editText in your first fragment.